alternative to impersonation or LogonUser
Some winform application built and use the impersonation to access/write the shared folder on network using service account. This is to prevent assign the access rights directly to the end user.
Is there any alternative for this impersonation using Logonuser method for winform application. As recently new server policy doesnt allow this impersonation

Why have you tagged this as c# and vb.net? What was the reason for that new policy?

the program built in c#

Ok, that explains the tag c# but not the tag vb.net and not the reason for the new policy

The question is unclear or is trying to not ask what it wants to ask - whether one can use a username/password instead of Windows authentication. The answer is no. The very notion of Windows authentication is that you connect using your account. When you use a shared folder in a domain, both computers know who the user is. They don't exchange credentials. Instead, requests are authenticated using Kerberos tickets

@SirRufo I'd bet the new policy wants to stop hacks like this. Probably too many logs saying AaronArnold tried to access the same folder 1000 times in the same second

This is to prevent assign the access rights directly to the end user. why? That's the actual problem and a serious security issue. In any case, you may be able to mount the shared folder as a local drive with specific credentials using net use or New-PSDrive in Powershell

No, there is not a way to do this without giving users explicit access to the network resource.  You can tighten your application's security by impersonating a service account that only has access to the network folder in question.  Also, for auditing, add logging to the application so you can correlate actions by the service user with actions by a specific user.
